# Wordpress FontAwesome doubles icons on hover

Tags: font-awesome

So I have FontAwesome include as a part of a theme I am using in wordpress and I wanted to add some custom animations to the icon element.

But when adding my custom css, it 'works' but when hovering over the element/icon I get that same element/icon in the background, it's like it has double somehow.

Don't know what to put from the code that is relevant, I haven't found anything that can do this in the css.

Image of how it looks:
[image]

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u tried like that way?

CSS:

```
your_element:hover{
 content:"" !important;
}
```

Comment: FontAwesome may have other stylesheets based on hover with attached content for viewing icons, u can find and delete these.